# Serverless config credentials not working when serverless.yml file present

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, bitbucket-pipelines

We're trying to deploy our lambda using serverless on BitBucket pipelines, but we're running into an issue when running the `serverless config credentials` command.  This issue also happens in docker containers, and locally on our machines.

This is the command we're running:

```
serverless config credentials --stage staging --provider aws --key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY --secret $AWS_ACCESS_SECRET
```

And it gives us the error:

```
Error: Profile default does not exist
```

The profile is defined in our serverless.yml file.  If we rename the serverless file before running the command, it works, and then we can then put the serverless.yml file back and successfully deploy.

e.g.

```
            - mv serverless.yml serverless.old
            - serverless config credentials --stage beta --provider aws --key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY --secret $AWS_ACCESS_SECRET
            - mv serverless.old serverless.yml
```

We've tried adding the `--profile default` switch on there, but it makes no difference.

It's worth noting that this wasn't an issue until we started to use the SSM Parameter Store within the serverless file, the moment we added that, it started giving us the `Profile default does not exist` error.

**serverless.yml (partial)**

```
service: our-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-west-1
  profile: default
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action: 'ssm:GetParameter'
      Resource:
        - 'arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:0000000000:parameter/our-service-launchdarkly-key-dev'
        - 'arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:0000000000:parameter/our-service-launchdarkly-key-beta'
        - 'arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:0000000000:parameter/our-service-launchdarkly-key-staging'
        - 'arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:0000000000:parameter/our-service-launchdarkly-key-live'
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action: 'kms:Decrypt'
      Resource:
        - 'arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:0000000000:key/alias/aws/ssm'

  environment:
    LAUNCH_DARKLY_SDK_KEY: ${self:custom.launchDarklySdkKey.${self:provider.stage}}

custom:
  stages:
    - dev
    - beta
    - staging
    - live

  launchDarklySdkKey:
    dev: ${ssm:/our-service-launchdarkly-key-dev~true}
    beta: ${ssm:/our-service-launchdarkly-key-beta~true}
    staging: ${ssm:/our-service-launchdarkly-key-staging~true}
    live: ${ssm:/our-service-launchdarkly-key-live~true}

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-stage-manager

...
```

**TLDR:** serverless config credentials only works when serverless.yml isn't present, otherwise it complains about profile default not existing, only an issue when using SSM Param store in the serverless file.

Answer (score 5):

The `profile` attribute in your `serverless.yaml` refers to saved credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`.  If a `[default]` entry is not present in that file, serverless will complain.  I can think of 2 possible solutions to this:

1. Try removing `profile` from your `serverless.yaml` completely and using environment variables only.
2. Leave `profile: default` in your `serverless.yaml` but set the credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=***************
aws_secret_access_key=***************
```

If you go with #2, you don't have to run `serverless config credentials` anymore.

Comment: The latest version of the Serverless Framework is v2.26.0. Perhaps if you're that far behind, you should try the latest release? And if that fails, report the bug so the maintainers can fix it: https://github.com/serverless/serverless